# Error while adding records to access database from c#.net

Tags: c#, ms-access

Code:

```
    int MaxRows = 0;
    int inc = 0;

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        ds1 = new DataSet();

        con.ConnectionString = " Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:/Documents and Settings/user/My Documents/anchu.accdb";
        string sql = "SELECT * From Table1";
        da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);

        con.Open();

        da.Fill(ds1, "Table1");
        //NavigateRecords();

        con.Close();
        //con.Dispose();
    }
    /*private void NavigateRecords()
    {
        DataRow drow = ds1.Tables["Table1"].Rows[0];

        textBox1.Text = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
        textBox2.Text = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
        textBox3.Text = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
        textBox4.Text = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();
    }*/

    private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();
        textBox4.Clear();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder cb;
        cb = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da);

        DataRow drow = ds1.Tables["Table1"].NewRow();
        drow[0] = textBox1.Text;
        drow[1] = textBox2.Text;
        drow[2] = textBox3.Text;
        drow[3] = textBox4.Text;

        ds1.Tables["Table1"].Rows.Add(drow);

        MaxRows = MaxRows + 1;
        inc = MaxRows - 1;
        da.Update(ds1, "Table1");

        MessageBox.Show("Entry Added");
    }
}
```

}

I am getting an error in the line:

da.Update(ds1, "Table1");

The error says..OleDBException was unhandled

and below that it says..Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

I have connected my access database correctly as well.

My table format  is as follows

**FIELD NAME**
Sno.(primary key)
Name
Company Name
Contact Number

**Datatype**
Text 
Text
Text
Text

Comment: `da.Update()` isn't a part of the code sample you provided. It's likely the problem is in that part of the code. What troubleshooting have you tried thus far?

Comment: i did not do anything.. i am just trying to edit the access fields.. where i deleted the first field-SNo. and even now i have the same error

Comment: When you say you didn't do anything, does that mean that it was working and has stopped working recently, or is this new code that has never worked?

Comment: It looks like that is an insert not an update.

Comment: can u give me the code snippet please?

Answer (score 0):

Could be either/both:

1)open and close a connection around the update statement

2)set the updatecommand property of the adapter. see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) page