# Add a new record to the Access database

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error while adding records to access database from c#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626977/error-while-adding-records-to-access-database-from-c-net)

I need to add a new record to an Access database using the below code, but I get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. I tried to solve it but I could not get a solution. How should I overcome this error?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con;
        DataSet ds1;
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter da;
        int MaxRows = 0;
        int inc = 0;

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
            ds1 = new DataSet();
            con.ConnectionString ="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=C:/Users/JaYam/Documents/jaya.accdb";
            string sql = "SELECT * From Table1"; 
            da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
            con.Open();
            da.Fill(ds1, "Table1");
            NavigateRecords(); 
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
        private void NavigateRecords()
        {
            DataRow drow =ds1.Tables["Table1"].Rows[0];
            textBox1.Text = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
            textBox2.Text = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
            textBox3.Text = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
            textBox4.Text = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();
            textBox4.Clear();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
            ds1 = new DataSet();
            con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:/Users/JaYam/Documents/jaya.accdb";
            string sql = "SELECT * From Table1";
            da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
            con.Open();
            da.Fill(ds1, "Table1");
            NavigateRecords();


            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder cb;
            cb = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
            DataRow dRow = ds1.Tables["Table1"].NewRow();
            //dRow[0] = textBox1.Text;
            dRow[1] = textBox2.Text;
            dRow[2] = textBox3.Text;
            dRow[3] = textBox4.Text;
            dRow[4] = textBox4.Text;
            ds1.Tables["Table1"].Rows.Add(dRow);
            MaxRows = MaxRows + 1;
            inc = MaxRows - 1;
            da.Update(ds1, "Table1");
            MessageBox.Show("Entry Added");
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should give us more information, to start with. *Where* are you getting the exception?

Comment: On what line does the error occur?

Comment: Also please don't include all sorts of code not relevant to your question - some people might not make the effort to read all of that. Also please make some attempt to format it in a readable way; I've done it for you this time.

Comment: da.update(ds1,"Table1"); -this line shows an error of unhandled exception , now it shows an error in this line  dRow[4] = textBox4.Text;

Comment: ya , thank you Bridge , but i did it from homeandlearn website and i'm totally new to this language , so i dont knw wat to delete and wat not to

Comment: What's the idea? Two names, but identical code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626977/error-while-adding-records-to-access-database-from-c-net

Comment: OP - Your last edit did nothing but format the code to what it already was, and re-introduce grammatical and spelling errors I'd previously corrected - therefore rolled back (again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access a fifth, non-existent column by `dRow[4]`. The 4 means you're trying to access the fifth element since indexes are zero-based in most programming languages. The first index is 0, the second is 1, the third is 2, et c.

Consider this piece of code, where you fetch the values:

```
textBox1.Text = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
textBox2.Text = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
textBox3.Text = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
textBox4.Text = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();
```

Notice how you fetch value at place 0 into `textBox1`. You need to replicate this behaviour when you try to save your values, so assign `dRow[0]` the value of `textBox1`, `dRow[1]` the value of `textBox2`, et c.

It looks like you've made a simple copying mistake, since you already do assign the value of `textBox4` to `dRow[3]` (correctly), and on the next row you try to do the same with `dRow[4]` which is a column that simply does not exist.

---

Per your update - it seems you're trying to add a new row and assign a value to column 0 which is an autoincrement column. The database will handle this column itself, you don't need to assign values to that.

Comment: Thanq sir , but i have got a new error now . its on the line da.update(ds1,"Table1"); . It shows oleDb exception not handled

Comment: Debug your application and look at the InnerException of that particular exception to see more details, perhaps?

Comment: I did sir , thank you .It shows that syntax error in the INSERT INTO statement .can u give me the code snippets ?

Comment: ok sir . thanks . so how do i write the code ? i'm very new to this , can u help me out in giving me the code for adding a new record to access ?

Comment: Just remove `dRow[0] = textBox1.Text;` and see what happens.

Comment: Still i get the error , oledb exception unhandled . how do i overcome it ?

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that either you don't have any rows in the database (and therefore Rows[0] in NavigateRecords(..) doesn't actually exist), or you are trying to get a column value that doesn't exist. Are you sure you have 4 columns in that table?

Comment: Ya i have 4 columns .the table goes like this SLID -Autonumber , custname-text ,contact number-text , Address-text .

Comment: @Jaya Actually your code assumes you have five columns - indexes are zero-based in most programming languages, meaning the first column is 0, the second is 1, etc.

Comment: I think @J.Steen has it.

Comment: Thanq sir , it worked . i have got a new error of oleDb exception not handled ..